# Calculate a new value after applying group by on some columns for snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to calculate a new values by dividing one value by other value which is in same column.
Here's the example of my table

```
REGION  COUNTRY STATE   VALUEX  INDICATOR
A         B      D       20       IND1
A         B      D       10       IND2
A         B      E       20       IND1
A         B      E       10       IND2
```

Expected table result

```
REGION  COUNTRY STATE   VALUEX  INDICATOR
A         B      D       2        IND3
A         B      E       2        IND3
```

from the expected result we can see that column "REGION COUNTRY STATE" is grouped and value is calculated i.e IND1/IND2 and this value is assigned to new INIDCATOR "IND3"

Snowflake query

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  Region   VARCHAR
 ,Country  VARCHAR
 ,State  VARCHAR
 ,ValueX INT
 ,Indicator VARCHAR
)
AS
  SELECT *
    FROM VALUES
           ('A','B','D',20,'IND1')
          ,('A','B','D',10,'IND2')
          ,('A','B','E',20,'IND1')
          ,('A','B','E',10,'IND2')
;
```

I am new to Snowflake. Not sure how to form this output. Did not find any answers in Internet. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a non-pivot answer can be:

```
WITH data AS (
 SELECT *
    FROM VALUES
           ('A','B','D',20,'IND1')
          ,('A','B','D',10,'IND2')
          ,('A','B','E',20,'IND1')
          ,('A','B','E',10,'IND2')
    v( Region, Country, State, ValueX, Indicator)
)


SELECT region, 
    country, 
    state,
    SUM(IFF(Indicator='IND1', ValueX, null)) as ind1,
    SUM(IFF(Indicator='IND2', ValueX, null)) as ind2, 
    ind1/ind2 as valuex,
    'IND3' as indicator
FROM data
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

which can be rolled into a working answer of:

```
SELECT region, 
    country, 
    state,
    SUM(IFF(Indicator='IND1', ValueX, null))/SUM(IFF(Indicator='IND2', ValueX, null)) as valuex,
    'IND3' as indicator
FROM data
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

| REGION | COUNTRY | STATE | VALUEX | INDICATOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | D | 2 | IND3 |
| A | B | E | 2 | IND3 |

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the pivot functionality as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html).

```
select region, country, state, ind1/ind2 as valuex, 'IND3' as indicator
from my_table
pivot(sum(valuex) for indicator in ('IND1', 'IND2')) as p (region, country, state, ind1, ind2);
```